# How do I enable UHCI USB support in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, usb, usb-3

I've got a USB Fight Stick controller (Madcatz SFIV TE) that only supports the UHCI USB standard. I've done some research online that led me to find out that USB 3 ports support this standard, but in Windows it doesn't work. I've successfully tested this controller in Linux, and confirmed it only works in my USB3 ports, but booting into Windows causes it to be recognized, but none of the inputs work.

I found this page here: http://batcmd.com/windows/7/services/usbuhci/ which creates a batch file to enable the usbuhci.sys driver, but it doesn't work for me.

If I try to start it manually here's the error message I get:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>sc start usbuhci
[SC] StartService FAILED 1058:

The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it.
```

So, I'm running out of ideas on how to get this device working under Windows, and would appreciate any help. I've seen that I can buy a PCB replacement, but I'd like to see if there's another way first.

Comment: The batch just starts a service item, does the service exist ? > SC Query usbuhci .  Is it possible there was a USB3 driver needed for your motherboard to make use of all the features of the USB3 ports?  I test the same thing here, and the service attempts starting then gives the same error. services will do that when they are not needed, and should start properly themselves when the device/driver is seen needing it? So the particular error is "normal".   How does the input device show up in the windows "Device Manager"?

Comment: @Psycogeek The service does exist, and it's in a "STOPPED" state. The input device shows up as "PC USB Wired Stick 8838". All of the information is the same as on [this page](http://controllermax.com/forums/showthread.php?t=144636).